# URL won't print to text file

Tags: google-chrome, batch-file, url, text

I have just found out about Chrome 80's Deep linking functionality. I decided that I wanted to make a script that I would paste the URL and paste the text I want to link to in, and it would print to a text file what the resulting URL is.

The problem I am having is that it won't print to the text file.

Here is the code.

```
@ECHO OFF
Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set /p url="Enter URL:"
set /p highlight="Enter Highlighted Text:"
set highlightResult=!highlight: =%%20!
set displayURL = %url% + "#:~:text=" + %highlightResult%
echo %displayURL%
echo %displayURL% >> url.txt
PAUSE
```

I have tried multiple variations of doing about the same thing, but it is only printing "ECHO OFF" into the text file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got a couple of things wrong here. First and foremost, spaces are significant in `set` statements in batch, which means that you're actually setting a variable called `%displayURL %`.

Secondly, you concatenate strings in batch simply by putting the strings next to each other; no need for `+` or whatever other symbols other languages use.

`set displayURL=%url%#:~:text=%highlightResult%`

Answer (score 0):

A couple of additional points -

In using Set /p and user input, Doublequoting the setting of variables: `Set "url:Enter url:"`, and expanding with `!expansion!` as opposed to `%expansion%` will avoid alot of issues that arise through entry of certain characters by the user. an example is:

```
@ECHO OFF & Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
For /L %%A in (1,1,100) Do (
set /p "url=Enter URL:"
set /p "highlight=Enter Highlighted Text:"
set "highlightResult=!highlight: =%%20!"
set "displayURL=!url! "#:~:text=" !highlightResult!"
echo(!displayURL!
echo(!displayURL!>>"url.txt"
)
PAUSE
```

**Example output:**

`Enter URL:https://www.google.com
Enter Highlighted Text:this&that<>plus the (other)
https://www.google.com "#:~:text=" this&that<>plus%20the%20(other)`

The use of the `For /L` loop is simply another way to allow multiple entries.

using `echo(!Var!` as opposed to `echo !Var!` prevents unintended whitespace, and results in an empty line instead of the line `Echo is Off` that results when the variable is undefined.

doublequoting filepaths: `"url.txt"` is a good habit to get into to prevent issues, particularly when files / folder names contain spaces.

Comment: `echo(` doesn't prevent unintended whitespace, but it does keep things from breaking if there's an executable called `echo` somewhere in your system path (and it will prevent `echo is Off` if the variable is unset)